# Creating components in Angular rules

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, frontend

What determines when to create a new component in Angular 2+? For example - we have a landing page to code. And now - in which way dividing this site for distinct components, like HeaderComponent, NavComponent, AboutCompanyComponent...
Which statements need to be spend to create a new component? Is there a view key or functionalities or even some other?

Comment: Take a look into the angular tutorial to get started https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I generally follow the below rules

1. component should be smaller
2. separation of concern, I avoid mixing header and footer.
3. If the same component is going to be used at multiple places.
4. Smart and presentational component when doing state management.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the all logic and html in one component but creating different components for different sections of page e.g. header, footer e.t.c. allows you to manage logic and html of a section separately avoiding conflicts in logic. It also provides easily maintainable and contained logic and template for each section. The file sizes of  template and logic file for each section also remains small which means if you see an issue in a section of a page, you know which file to edit rather than finding the issue in a large file. 
Reuse ability is also an advantage of using components e.g. if you want to use a Rating component on different pages, you can create a single rating component and reuse it. 
Hope it clarifies.